# Guest module for phpFox 3

Tags: phpfox

I have installed phpFox and I want to add to my website guest module how can I do this!

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I think you should make your question more specific or others will be hard to help you.

As I understand, you want to add Guest module into your website. There're 2 possible cases :

- You already have package that contains Guest module: all you have to do is extracting that package into your website and go to AdminCP/Extensions/Product/Import Product/ then choose Guest product and click install
- If you don't have that package, you need to contact your package provider to get one then do as I say above